# Android Studio Not Showing Colors

Tags: android-studio

I was using android studio for layers theme and it was easy to theme with android studio as i can see the colors in studio itself on left side check the screenshot what i was referring

[image]

but in CM13 template i dont know whats wrong its not showing colors. i am new to android studio is there something wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can find a solution to this problem in the comments to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122917/3094065)

Answer (score 2):

happened to me in my Mac:

go to File uncheck powersaver mode if u have kept it checked.

Comment: which file, please!

Comment: Top left of your Android Studio has a File menu.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `Preferences`->`Appearances` and enable `Show CSS color preview as background`.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling either power saver mode or essential highlighting in File will fix the problem.